# send GET request without loading page in php

Tags: php, get

Hi i have a form after the submit i want to run url  in background with out goin to the page it self

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
http://url/default/en_US/send.html?u=admin&p=hodamai&l=1&n=01211200671&m='

}
```

Comment: This sounds like an AJAX-call? Is that what you try to accomplish? In that case you need to perform the call in JavaScript or jQuery. Capture the submit event and use ajax to call another url and receive the result.

Comment: @Gowire Or he can pefrom a [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) request

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an AJAX-Request to your server. That means your browser makes a background-request to your server and execute the script while you're still on your homepage. Then you'll get the response as JSON. If you want, you could use fetch as well, but I prefer AJAX because even IE supports that. I think both are easy to use ;)

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp